# Language switch for Angular Material datepicker in lazy-loaded module

Tags: angular, angular-material

How can I switch the language of my material datepickers across the whole application (i.e. for datepickers in eagerly and lazy-loaded components)?

I created a stackblitz example demostrating my problem:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4cu4cb

As soon as the language is changed in the eagerly- or lazy-loaded component, I would like to change the language for both the datepickers. Unfortunately, this does not work yet.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I corrected your example on stackBlitz it seems the displayDormat is
>   an object not your locale format, you can access `this.locale` in the
>   adapter to have the right format for the dates.

```
if (this.locale === 'myCustomFormat') {      
      const day = date.getUTCDate();
      const month = date.getUTCMonth() + 1;
      const year = date.getFullYear();

      // Return the format as per your requirement
      return `${day}.${month}.${year}`;
    } else {
      // Refer to the standard formatting of the NativeDateAdapter.
      return super.format(date, displayFormat);
    }
```

> For the syncking problem between the components I will suggest a
>   service injected on the root of the app which holds your locale into
>   an observable and the date adapter will read the value from that
>   observable and formats the date corespondigly. I will have a look later on that also in hard to make the sync on stackblitz :D
>   [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6vupnn) is your example changed and I hope it gives you an idea on how to sync the services I didn't manage to make appLocale const a service which is injectable. Cause NativeDateAdapter constructor has some dependencyes on material design and your class is not injectable you can correct them to be angular services and inject all your params together with the observable and make the subscription in the constructor.
>
> Please have a look I hope this is what you need.

Answer (score -1):

Basically what i understood is you want to share data between components, one solution would be to use a *service*.

Also you can use *localStorage* to store your locale when its updated in one component and when the other component is loaded u can search for 'locale' in localStorage and update in *ngOnInit()* of that component.

As per your example what you can do is - 
in *app.component.ts* where you are having your french(), italian(), german() methods set the locale in localStorage :

```
localStorage.setItem('locale', 'fr'); // if its french()
localStorage.setItem('locale', 'it'); // if its italian()
localStorage.setItem('locale', 'de'); // if its german()
```

then in your test.component.ts have your class implementing **OnInit**

```
export class TestComponent  implements OnInit{ }

// then add ngOnInit() to check if the locale is there and set accordingly.
ngOnInit(){
if(localStorage.getItem('locale')){
  this.adapter.setLocale(localStorage.getItem('locale'));
 }
}
```

I think this will help addressing your requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am aware of localstorage and data sharing mechanisms, but I think this does not solve the problem. Basically, the DateAdapter should "dynamically" share the 'locale' but it does not for some reason at the moment.

Comment: How about having a service where we have getter and setter for locale and then at the component level using 
providers: [
    {provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: '<value from service>'}
  ]

Comment: As per documentation - "By default, the MAT_DATE_LOCALE injection token will use the existing LOCALE_ID locale code from @angular/core. If you want to override it, you can provide a new value for the MAT_DATE_LOCALE token"
I think the date picker will take the root locale in other components though we explicitly setLocale for DateAdapter in a single component.